# Redirection malfunctioning

Tags: .htaccess

I wanted to redirect `mysite.com/blog/any-thing/any-where/` to `mysite.com/any-thing/any-where/`, so I created an .htaccess as below:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works, but downfall, when I run `mysite.com/blog` it redirects to `mysite.com`.

How can I make sure that `mysite.com/blog/` doesn't redirect, but `mysite.com/blog/anything` redirects to `/anything`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tweak your regex like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It works for sure. Make sure there is no .htaccess in `/blog/` and you test in a new browser.